How to have code run over and over after a button was pressed once without a while loop
I'm new to C# and I'm creating a telemetry dashboard, and one of the buttons opens the serial monitor. When I press the button that opens it, I would like a loop that somehow doesn't freeze the other buttons like a while would.
I've tried using separate threads but to write to the form for a text box and a chart, I need the code to be in the same thread as the main loop. Is there a way that when I press the button, the code that writes to the charts will occur every time that a code "cycle" passes? I've tried using a timer but I haven't gotten it to work. Below I'll link the code (sorry about the extra chart_click it won't let me delete without errors)
namespace dashboard_telemetry
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Text = "Dashboard ver. 1";
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Open Button
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button_open.Text = "Opened";
            button_open.Enabled = true;
            button_close.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox_port.Text;
                serialPort1.Open();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Upon loading the Form
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                comboBox_port.Items.Add(port);
            }
            button_close.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void button_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button_open.Enabled = false;
            button_close.Enabled = true;
            serialPort1.Close();

        }

        private void textBox_Recieve_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
         
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// button1_1 is the button that starts logging data to charts
            serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxbaud.Text);
             if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    {
                        //This code will only run if I click the button  
                        // but I need it to run over and over 
                        string newPacket = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                        string[] data = newPacket.Split(',');
                        tBoxDataIN.Text = newPacket;
                        chart1.Series["Gyro X"].Points.AddXY(data[1], data[0]);
        }
       
    private void chart7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label_port_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox_port_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private static void SetTimer()
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void chart2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void chart4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Your code snippet is not compilable. Can you please be more specific and give a [mcve]?

Your code not only doesn't compile, but it makes no sense. Your button has to already be enabled, or the button_open_click could never be called, so why would you enable the button in that event? And where would the if block be located?

No, this is not possible.

I can only give you so much help because the question is a little vague.
private bool showSerialData = false;    // Use Variables to store state, you don't want to use Control Properties,   
// unless the data is attached to the control. Even then most  
// people would create a custom control that derives from the base control with their  
// own properties.

void Main() {
  while (true)    // This will freeze the UI thread,  I'm demo'ing a loop
  {
    if (showSerialData) //  == true)
    {
        // write serial data to charts
    }
    // TODO detect another variable or key stroke to exit.
  }
}

private void button_open_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Switchs on or off, the opposite of its last state
    showSerialData = !showSerialData;
}

